# On optimal packing of 11 squares inside square

Tags: math, optimization

I was wondering if one knows a suitable algorithm for the following problem.

We have been given 11 squares of side length 1. They can't overlap other squares. How small square can contain those eleven squares?

Okay, this is unsolved, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8698/eleven-unit-squares-inside-a-larger-square . But how good results one can find by a computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best known optimal solution was found by [Walter Trump in 1979](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Trump#cite_note-1).

This problem is a packing problem, more specifically, a [square packing in a square problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_packing_in_a_square).

If you want to find solutions algorithmically, you should go for an approximate methods based on a 2d packing heuristic or a metaheuristic such as evolutionary algorithms. There is a lot of literature around each problem and algorithm in combinatorial optimization. It could be a research per itself.

After a quick googling, below some links to start with:

- [An approximation algorithm for square packing](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/%7Evanstee/square2.pdf)
- [Packing Square into Squares](http://www.ime.usp.br/%7Ecris/gcomb/pronex/ps-dvi-files/yo/pack_square_square.ps.gz)
- [An algorithm for packing squares](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316597928363)
- [Combinatorial algorithms for packing and scheduling problems](https://www.uni-siegen.de/fb6/aan/optimierung/publikationen/download/habil.pdf)

Comment: Yes. The result is dues to Trump. I just haven't found a proof for the side length so I was wondering a method to verify the result.

Comment: According my reading, it seems Trump didn't find an exact model for it. I didn't find anything about that, sorry. However, the following could interest you: [Improved Dense Packings of Congruent Squares in a Square](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00454-004-1129-z?LI=true) and [discussion about new packing of unit squares in square](https://groups.google.com/group/alt.math.recreational/tree/browse_frm/month/2005-11/331fc0e4b26df652?rnum=11&lnk=nl).